# Вытащить из массива только один элемент

Tags: массивы, breakpoint

Нужно чтобы из массива было распечатано только: "I love Matilda". Сделать это нужно при помощи цикла **for** и ключевого слова **break**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String [] friends = new String [20];
    friends [0] = "Masha";
    friends [1] = "Matilda";
    friends [2] = "Rosa";
    friends [18] = "Hillary";
    friends [19] = "Natasha";

    int totalElements = friends.length;
    int i = 0;

    while (i<totalElements) {


    if (friends [i] == null) {

    i++;
        // Go back to check the while expression
    continue;

    }
        System.out.println("I love " + friends [i]);
        i++;

}

        System.out.println("The iteration is over");
}
```

}

Comment: Ну так и сравнивайте `friends[i] != "Matilda"` и после в конце добавьте `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < friends.Length; i++)
    if (friends[i] == "Matilda") {
        System.out.println("I love " + friends[i]);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < totalElements; i++)
    if (friends[i] == "Matilda") {
        System.out.println("I love " + friends[i]);
        break;
    }  (результат такой же, что тут правильнее писать "i < totalElements"   или "i < friends.Length" ? или в этом случае без разницы?

Comment: @ДмитрийГорлач в данном случае без разницы, ведь вы присвоили переменной `totalElements` значение длины массива `friends` в строке `int totalElements = friends.length;`. Тут на свой вкус, хотя я бы рекомендовал писать `friends.length`, потому как не придется создавать новую переменную.